# Httpd & PHP error after upgrading to Monterey version 12.3.1

Tags: homebrew, apache, webserver

I recently upgrade my Mac to Monterey v12.3.1, and when I check the httpd and php, with `brew services list`, its return status Error.

I try to `tail -f /usr/local/var/log/httpd/error_log`, its return log:

```
[Thu Apr 14 13:39:49.922945 2022] [core:notice] [pid 36657] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/local/bin/httpd'
[Thu Apr 14 13:39:56.265887 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 36657] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Apr 14 13:40:02.577144 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 37034] AH00163: Apache/2.4.53 (Unix) PHP/8.0.17 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 14 13:40:02.577357 2022] [core:notice] [pid 37034] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/local/bin/httpd'
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Have you run `brew upgrade` after upgrading to Monterey?

Comment: @jaume yes, i run brew update and uprgrade after that.

Comment: But before i run that command, its already happen @jaume

Comment: Thank you, can you add the output of `brew doctor`,`httpd -v` and `php --version` to your question?